# pandas split string with $ special text style

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel, the data has two $ , when I read it using pandas, it will convert them to a very special text style.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Bid-Ask':['$185.25 - $186.10','$10.85 - $11.10','$14.70 - $15.10']})
```

[image: my excel]

after pd.read_excel

[image: after pd.read_excel]

```
df['Bid'] = df['Bid-Ask'].str.split('−').str[0]
```

above code doesn't work due to $ make my string into a special style text.the Split function doesn't work.

my expected result

[image]

Comment: You can try explicitly converting the column values to string: `df['Bid-Ask'].astype('str').str.split('−').str[0]` . Also, please provide something that can be reproduced. When I'm writing the dataframe to excel and reading the excel file, the behavior you have explained is not observed.

Comment: Are you sure this is not just a display issue? $ in jupyter notebook can be regarded as LaTeX and rendered with MathJax so you might try using the pandas option to turn that off and redisplay the dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not split. Using `str.extract` is likely the most robust:

```
df[['Bid', 'Ask']] = df['Bid-Ask'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
```

Output:

```
             Bid-Ask     Bid     Ask
0  $185.25 - $186.10  185.25  186.10
1    $10.85 - $11.10   10.85   11.10
2    $14.70 - $15.10   14.70   15.10
```

Comment: nice shot, do it in one line of code

Answer (score 0):

There is a `non-breaking space` (`\xa0`) in your string. That's why the split doesn't work.

I copied the strings (of your df) one by one into an Excel file and then imported it with `pd.read_excel`.
The column looks like this then:

```
repr(df['Bid-Ask'])
'0    $185.25\xa0- $186.10\n1      $10.85\xa0- $11.10\n2      $14.70\xa0- $15.10\nName: Bid-Ask, dtype: object'
```

Before splitting you can replace that and it'll work.

```
df['Bid-Ask'] = df['Bid-Ask'].astype('str').str.replace('\xa0',' ', regex=False)
df[['Bid', 'Ask']] = df['Bid-Ask'].str.replace('$','', regex=False).str.split('-',expand = True)
print(df)

             Bid-Ask      Bid      Ask
0  $185.25 - $186.10  185.25    186.10
1    $10.85 - $11.10   10.85     11.10
2    $14.70 - $15.10   14.70     15.10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the lambda function and apply the method together to split the column values into two and slice the value

```
df['Bid'] = df['Bid-Ask'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0].strip()[1:])
df['Ask'] = df['Bid-Ask'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[1].strip()[1:])
```

output:

```
      Bid-Ask       Bid      Ask
0    185.25− 186.10 185.25  186.1
1    10.85− 11.10   10.85   11.1
2    14.70− 15.10   14.70   15.1
```

Comment: No, you should really **not** use `apply` for this. This method is inefficient on several levels (`apply` is slow, you repeat the split for each new value, and this won't get rid of the `$` sign)